# How to completely remove ClaudiaIDE Extension in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio, extension, visual-studio-2022

I tried installing this extension (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kbuchi.ClaudiaIDE), and it was good, but then I decided to remove it. It was successfully uninstalled under Manage Extensions. However, even after removing it and restarting VS and my machine, the random background image still appears like this one:

[image]

How can I completely remove it?

Comment: Have you tried [resetting your environment settings](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/resetsettings-devenv-exe?view=vs-2022) within Visual Studio?

Comment: I haven't I'll try this

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same and found this thing here under the Extension menu in Visual Studio 2022:

[image: Path to "Toggle Background Image Visibility]